# Why does nginx still redirect urls when not configured for these urls - reverse proxy setup

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have the following conf

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

sendfile        on;

keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
            listen 8443 ssl;
            server_name unifi.bob.net;

            ssl on;
            ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
            ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
            ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;
            ssl_certificate /var/lib/docker/volumes/letsencrypt/_data/live/unifi.bob.net/fullchain.pem;
            ssl_certificate_key /var/lib/docker/volumes/letsencrypt/_data/live/unifi.bob.net/privkey.pem;

            location /wss/ {
                    proxy_pass https://192.168.1.3:8443;
                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    proxy_buffering off;
                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
                    proxy_read_timeout 86400;
            }

            location / {
                    proxy_pass https://192.168.1.3:8443/;
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            }
    }

    server {
            listen 8443 ssl;
            server_name nas.bob.net;

            ssl on;
            ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
            ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
            ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;
            ssl_certificate /var/lib/docker/volumes/letsencrypt/_data/live/nas.bob.net/fullchain.pem;
            ssl_certificate_key /var/lib/docker/volumes/letsencrypt/_data/live/nas.bob.net/privkey.pem;

            location / {
                    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.254:8080/;
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            }
    }


    server {
            listen 880;
            server_name unifi.bob.net;

            return 301 https://unifi.bob.net$request_uri;
    }

    server {
            listen 880;
            server_name nas.bob.net;

            return 301 https://nas.bob.net$request_uri;
    }


}
```

this all works fine if i hit http://nas.bob.net i get redirected to https://nas.bob.net and to the internal resource fine this also works the same for unifi.bob.net

however if i try my external ip or a record i get redirected to the unifi recource?

should it not just do nothing or am i missing something from the config?

Thanks

Comment: The request is handled by the default server. If you don't specify which server is default, it will use the first one with a matching listen directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names) for details. If you want to avoid this, you will need to define a catch-all server block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found to answer, i had no default_server set in any config. now added this and all working as expected

Thanks